# detect device using modernizr

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

i have designed a page which detects device using device width and based on that it loads respected js and css file. how do i evaluate 3 conditions in modernizr and which is the better way to detect device (desktop, mobile or tablet)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Modernizr.load([
                {
                    test: Modernizr.mq('(min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 728px)'),
                    yep : ['mob.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js'],
                    nope : 'pc.css'
                }
            ]);

            if (!Modernizr.borderradius) {
                $.getScript("jquery.corner.js", function () {
                    $("input").corner();
                });
            }

            if(!Modernizr.required) {
                $("#frmSearch").submit(function(){
                    if($.trim($("#txtSearch").val().length) == 0){
                        alert('Please, Enter some keyword');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: ok can you give me some example ? as i have alreday used modernizr.mq

Comment: first i want to detect the device by using 3 conditions. how do i write 3 conditions in modernizr ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do this in Modernizr, I would say don't try to write a three-way condition; write three separate true/false conditions.

ie rather than having one condition that says either "desktop", "mobile" or "tablet", you should have three conditions called "desktop", "mobile" or "tablet", each of which would be true or false.

Hopefully that answers your question.

However, the other point I would raise is how do you draw the line between these types?

It's easy to say an iPhone is a mobile and an iPad is a tablet, but there are devices at all sizes between these; where is the cut-off point that a mobile becomes a tablet? And what about the tablets that can connect to a base-unit to become a laptop?

The trouble you're going to have here is that the form factors are very fluid; so you may never be quite certain about some devices as to what category they belong in. You might be better off just making your site adjust dynamically to the screen resolution using responsive CSS and CSS media queries.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes you are right. i checked it by changing the browser window size and my UI gets bad. i want that if browser minimum width is 320px, it should display mobile ui. how do i make this change ?

Comment: and how do i write 3 conditions in modernizr to check for desktop, mobile and table ?

Comment: @chacko - with three separate calls to `Modernizr.load()`. How you define the differences between desktop, mobile and tablet is up to you, but you'll want a separate Modernizr.load() test for each distinct condition you want to check for, each with it's own `yep` and `nope` response.